# Reverse Geo Location Using Calls and sms and not using

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, phone-call

Hi I was thinking can you get the location of a phone number thru calls and try to triangulate their location using their cell service provides and then use the geo coder to display the phone that i am calling and place their location in my geocoder and show my location and their location and how far we are? is it even possible for a basic phone app to do this or do i need some custom hardware + software to do this?

anything will help , and thanks!

Comment: well I think the most difficult is to have the information of where the cell is.
You can check the API documentation of the target plataform to get the cell ID.

Comment: but is it possible to get the caller and target phone number just by calling them if so i know i can do this and thanks :D